# Transforming two index sum into single index sum

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I know this is a quite basic question, but I have been looking at it for more than I would like to admit and I simply don't see the solution. Namely, I have the sum:

$$\sum_{1\leq i < j \leq n} \frac{2}{j-i+1}$$
and this is claimed to be the same as the following sum:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{2}{k+1} (n-k)$$

When I tried writing this for some small n's I see that it indeed does work, but I fail to see how to derive it using substitution or something like that. I have tried writing $k:= j-i$ but I think I mess the bounds of sums somewhere and get the factor in the sum wrong.

Comment: Take a "good" partition of the space $\{(i,j), 1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant n\}$ such that two elements of a same subset (e.g. name it $A_k$) of the partition verify $j-i= j'-i' = k$. Then count the number of elements of $A_k$ and things will get clearer.

Comment: For every $k$ count how many pairs $(i,j), j-i=k$ are in the sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A_k = \{(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \mid 1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant n, \, j-i =k\}$, you have
$$\bigsqcup_{k = 1}^{n-1} A_k = \{(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \mid 1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant n\} = A$$

Now $\sharp A_k = n-k$ nice you only need to determine $i$ to have $j$ and $1 \leqslant i = j-k \leqslant n-k$.

So
$\begin{align*}
\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n} \frac{2}{j-i+1} &= \sum_{(i,j) \in A} \frac{2}{j-i+1}  = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{(i,j) \in A_k} \frac{2}{j-i+1} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{(i,j) \in A_k} \frac{2}{k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{2}{k+1}\left(\sum_{(i,j) \in A_k} 1\right) \\
&= \sum_{(i,j) \in A_k} \frac{2}{k+1} \sharp A_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{2(n-k)}{k+1}.
\end{align*}$

Comment: Thank you! Right what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A variation. We show the following is valid
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{1}{j-i+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{k+1}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{1}{j-i+1}}&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n\frac{1}{j-i+1}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-i}\frac{1}{j+1}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^i\frac{1}{j+1}\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{j+1}\sum_{i=j}^{n-1}1\tag{5}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-j}{j+1}}
\end{align*}
and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we write the sum as double sum.
- In (3) we shift the index of the inner sum and start with $j=1$.
- In (4) we change the order of the summation of the outer sum $i\to n-i$.
- In (5) we exchange the sums.